# React - JSX syntax issue, and how to iterate with map and display items on newlines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iteration, jsx, array.prototype.map

I'm a React noob and making a ToDo list style [Recipe List app](https://fcc-recipebox.surge.sh/). I have a functional component, Item.js, and I am using JSX and the map function to iterate through each recipe item and display them. I want each recipe item to appear on a new line, but when I use .map to iterate through them React puts the entire list of recipe items into one p tag instead of one p tag for each item.

How can I iterate through the recipe items and display them on separate lines? Even if I try to display them as an unordered list React wants to throw each item in one li tag.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';


const Item = (props) => (
  <div>
    <div className="Recipe-Item-Container" key={props.text}>

        {props.items.map((item, index) => 
        <div className="Recipe-Item" key={index}>

            <h3>{item}</h3>

            <p>{props.ingredients[index]}</p>

          <div className="buttons-container">
            <Button className="edit-button" onClick={() => props.edit(item, index)}>Edit</Button>
            <Button className="delete-button" onClick={() => props.delete(item, index)}>Delete</Button>
          </div>

        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
)


export default Item;
```

Also on the `{props.items.map((item, index) =>`  line if I add a curly brace after the => I get an error. I have a React/JSX linter installed and it isn't catching anything. What's the issue?

I know this is probably a noob error but JSX is throwing me for a loop here.

Comment: `.map` requires a `return`

Answer (score 1):

If you add curly braces after the fat arrow, you will have to explicitly return the `JSX`.

```
const Item = (props) => (
  <div>
    <div className="Recipe-Item-Container" key={props.text}>

      {props.items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
              <div className="Recipe-Item" key={index}>

              <h3>{item}</h3>

              <p className="ingredients-list">
                   {props.ingredients[index].map((ingredient, ingredientIndex) => {
                      return (
                           <div className="ingredient" key={ingredient}>
                               {ingredient}
                           </div>
                     )
                   }}
              </p>

              <div className="buttons-container">
                <Button className="edit-button" onClick={() => props.edit(item, index)}>Edit</Button>
                <Button className="delete-button" onClick={() => props.delete(item, index)}>Delete</Button>
              </div>

            </div>
          )
        }
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: That resolved the curly bracket issue, thanks. But how can I go about displaying each item on a new line? Do I need to use a second .map on the p tag?

Comment: If `props.ingredients[index]` spits out multiple values, then ya you will have to map over it again and encase them inside a container.

Comment: This solves the displaying each item on a new line issue but unfortunately it breaks my program and I get a `TypeError: props.ingredients[index].map is not a function` error now when I try to edit the ingredient list on button click.

Comment: What is the output of `props.ingredients[index]`. As maps only work on array objects. Also how do `delete` and `edit` function looks like ?

Comment: The initial state is an array, but I have a handleChange function and an onEditSubmit function that take user edited items and update the state. Could this be the issue? Here is the code. https://github.com/Nicknyr/FCC_Recipe_Box/blob/master/src/App.js#L25]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working version.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [ "Pumpkin Pie", "Spaghetti", "Onion Pie" ],
    ingredients: [
      [ "Pumpkin Puree", "Sweetened Condensed Milk", "Eggs", "Pumpkin Pie Spice", "Pie Crust" ],
      [ "Noodles", "Tomatoe", "Sauce", "Meatballs" ],
      [ "Onion", "Pie Crust" ],
    ],
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box">
        <Item items={this.state.items} ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Item = props => (
  <div>
    <div className="Recipe-Item-Container" key={props.text}>

      {props.items.map( ( item, index ) => (
        <div className="Recipe-Item" key={item}>

          <h3>{item}</h3>
          <ul>
            {
              props.ingredients[ index ].map( ingredient =>
                <li key={ingredient}>{ingredient}</li> )
            }
          </ul>


          <div className="buttons-container">
            <button className="edit-button" onClick={() => props.edit( item, index )}>Edit</button>
            <button className="delete-button" onClick={() => props.delete( item, index )}>Delete</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      ) )}
    </div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

But if I were you I would change my state shape. Something like that:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      {
        name: "Pumpkin Pie",
        ingredients: [
          "Pumpkin Puree",
          "Sweetened Condensed Milk",
          "Eggs",
          "Pumpkin Pie Spice",
          "Pie Crust"
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Spaghetti",
        ingredients: ["Noodles", "Tomatoe", "Sauce", "Meatballs"]
      },
      {
        name: "Onion Pie",
        ingredients: ["Onion", "Pie Crust"]
      }
    ]
  };

  removeItem = item => {
    const newItems = this.state.items.filter(el => el.name !== item.name);
    this.setState({ items: newItems });
  };

  editItem = item => alert(`${item.name} will be edited`);

  renderItems = () =>
    this.state.items.map(item => (
      <Item
        key={item.name}
        item={item}
        removeItem={this.removeItem}
        editItem={this.editItem}
      />
    ));

  render() {
    return <div className="box">{this.renderItems()}</div>;
  }
}

const Item = props => {
  const { item, removeItem, editItem } = props;
  const handleRemove = () => removeItem(item);
  const handleEdit = () => editItem(item);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="Recipe-Item-Container" key={props.text}>
        <div className="Recipe-Item">
          <h3>{item.name}</h3>
          <ul>
            {item.ingredients.map(ingredient => (
              <li key={ingredient}>{ingredient}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <div className="buttons-container">
            <button className="edit-button" onClick={handleEdit}>
              Edit
            </button>
            <button className="delete-button" onClick={handleRemove}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Changes**

- State shape: Instead of holding two arrays, we are keeping an object per item. This object has a `name` and `ingredients` property. Maybe in the future, it may have a unique `id`? Objects are flexible.
- Instead of passing all the items to an `Item` component, we are mapping the items in the parent component and pass just one item to the `Item` component.
- We still have handler functions defined in the parent. But, we are not using them directly in the button's callback with an arrow function. So, they are not recreated in every render. Also, we don't have to use an index to pass the items back to the parent. We have the `item` prop itself! You can see how we handle the remove functionality: with `.filter` You can apply the same functionality to other functions. `.map`, `.filter`, `Object.assign` or spread syntax are all good tools. Just, avoid mutating your state directly.