# React - Iterate through state using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iteration, state, setstate

I'm relatively new to React and creating a ToDoList style [Recipe App](https://fcc-recipebox.surge.sh/). The user should be able to add new recipes to the list as well as delete or edit existing recipes.

I ran into an issue getting the ingredients to display on separate lines and [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320484/react-jsx-syntax-issue-and-how-to-iterate-with-map-and-display-items-on-newli) on how to do that. The end result was that I added a second `.map` function within my container to iterate through ingredients and display each one as a new paragraph element. Here is my container, `Item.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';


const Item = (props) => (
  <div>
    <div className="Recipe-Item-Container" key={props.text}>
      {/* Iterates through recipe item names and displays them */}
      {props.items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
        <div className="Recipe-Item" key={index}>
          <h3>{item}</h3>

         // This is what I added
        {/* Iterates through recipe ingredients and displays them*/}
        <p className="ingredients-list">
          {props.ingredients[index].map((ingredient, ingredientIndex) => {
            return (
              <div className="ingredient" key={ingredient}>
                {ingredient}
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </p>

        <div className="buttons-container">
          <Button className="edit-button" onClick={() => props.edit(item, index)}>Edit</Button>
          <Button className="delete-button" onClick={() => props.delete(item, index)}>Delete</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  )}
  </div>
</div>
)

export default Item;
```

Now the initial recipes within my state properly display ingredients on new lines, and any recipe item the user edits also displays ingredients on a new line. Exactly what I wanted.

The issue is when the user adds a new recipe the ingredients aren't displayed on new lines the way I want. If you click the add new recipe button and add a new one the ingredients are displayed side by side and as one single paragraph element.

I have two functions that handle adding a new recipe and editing an existing recipe, `onSubmit` and `onEditSubmit`. `onEditSubmit` is working fine because when recipes are edited the ingredients display properly on separate lines. `onSubmit` is the issue. How can I change `onSubmit` and get it to display ingredients on new lines and as separate paragraphs? I think this is an issue with how I am setting state within `onSubmit` and might involve the use of the spread operator.

Here is my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Item from './Item';
import './App.css';
import ModalComponent from './Modal.js';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import EditModalComponent from './EditModal.js';
import SimpleStorage from "react-simple-storage";


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: ["Pumpkin Pie", "Spaghetti", "Onion Pie"],
      ingredients:[
        ["Pumpkin Puree ", "Sweetened Condensed Milk ", "Eggs ", "Pumpkin Pie Spice ", "Pie Crust "],
        ["Noodles ", "Tomato Sauce ", "(Optional) Meatballs "],
        ["Onion ", "Pie Crust "]
      ],

      // Recipe name and ingredients
      inputVal: '',
      ingredientVal: '',
      // Recipe name and ingredients when user is editing existing recipe
      inputValEdit: '',
      ingredientValEdit: '',
      // Controls whether forms are displayed or hidden
      showRecipeForm: false,
      showRecipeEditForm: false,
      // Index to select which recipe item is being edited
      editingIndex: ''
    };

  }

  // Get text user inputs for recipes
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };


  // When user submits recipe this adds it to the list
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      items: [...this.state.items, this.state.inputVal],
      ingredients: [...this.state.ingredients, [this.state.ingredientVal]],
      showRecipeForm: false
    });

  }

  // When user edits existing recipe this adds it to the list
  onEditSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {items, ingredients, inputValEdit, ingredientValEdit, editingIndex} = this.state;

    // Selects proper recipe item to edit
    items[editingIndex] = inputValEdit;
    ingredients[editingIndex] = ingredientValEdit.split(',');


    this.setState({
      items: items,
      ingredients: ingredients,
      inputVal: '',
      ingredientVal: '',
      showRecipeEditForm: false
    });
  }

  closeRecipeForm = () => {
    this.setState({
      showRecipeForm: false,
      showRecipeEditForm: false
    });
  }

  // Shows recipe
  AddRecipe = (bool) => {
    this.setState({
      showRecipeForm: bool
    });
  }

  // Is called when one of the edit recipe buttons is clicked, shows RecipeEditForm
  edit = (item, index) => {
    this.setState({
      showRecipeEditForm: !this.state.showRecipeEditForm,
      editingIndex: index
    });
  }

  // Deletes recipe item from the list
  delete = (item, index) => {
     this.setState({
      ingredients : this.state.ingredients.filter((_, i) => i !== index),
      items: this.state.items.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">

        {/* Handles storing data in local sessions via react-simple-storage*/}
        <SimpleStorage parent={this} />

        <h1>Recipe List</h1>


        <ModalComponent
          inputVal={this.state.inputVal}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          ingredientVal={this.state.ingredientVal}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
          addRecipe={this.addRecipe}
          showRecipeForm={this.state.showRecipeForm}
          closeRecipeForm={this.closeRecipeForm}
        />

        <EditModalComponent
          inputValEdit={this.state.inputValEdit}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          ingredientValEdit={this.state.ingredientValEdit}
          onEditSubmit={this.onEditSubmit}
          closeRecipeForm={this.closeRecipeForm}
          addRecipe={this.addRecipe}
          showRecipeEditForm={this.state.showRecipeEditForm}
        />


        <Item
          items={this.state.items}
          ingredients={this.state.ingredients}
          edit={this.edit}
          delete={this.delete}
        />

      <Button className="add-recipe-button" onClick={this.AddRecipe}>Add New Recipe</Button>

      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Do I need to make `onSubmit` more similar to `onEditSubmit`? If so how can I do this?

Comment: Is not clear what the `this.ingredientVal` variable is, if it is a `string` with the same format as `ingredientValEdit `, you'll need to use `[...this.state.ingredients, this.state.ingredientVal.split(",")]` instead of `[...this.state.ingredients, [this.state.ingredientVal]]`

Comment: I ran into this issue with strings/arrays in my state: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357428/react-is-not-a-function-error-when-passing-function-as-props-to-functional-c

Comment: Yes but there you were using `ingredients: [...this.state.ingredients, this.state.ingredientVal]` not `ingredients: [...this.state.ingredients, this.state.ingredientVal.split(",")]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your store, your ingredients variable is an array of arrays.`[ [a, b] , [c, d]]`

You need to follow this format as you did in onEditSubmit. The `.split()` function return an array and save it into state.

Change the part in onSubmit

```
this.setState({
    items: [...this.state.items, this.state.inputVal],
    ingredients: [...this.state.ingredients, [this.state.ingredientVal]],
    showRecipeForm: false
});
```

to

```
this.setState({
    items: [...this.state.items, this.state.inputVal],
    ingredients: [...this.state.ingredients, this.state.ingredientVal.split(',')],
    showRecipeForm: false
});
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Got confused about a previous change I made and that appears to be the issue. Thanks.